# Длинная ссылка в email-рассылке в gmail переносится на новую строку, а в яндекс-почте ломает верстку

Tags: вёрстка-email

Длинная ссылка в email-рассылке в gmail переносится на новую строку, а в яндекс-почте ломает верстку.
Нюанс в том, что ссылка создается динамически, `<wbr>`расставить не получится.

Comment: поместите ссылку в href. а текст по ссылке назовите: тут

Comment: Если правильно понял проблему, то нужно так же динамически привести ссылку к удобному виду - через автоскрипт укорачивания ссылки, причем можно не заморачиваться с количеством уникально генерируемых символов, а взять минимум + время формирования короткой ссылки (или только время формирования) - уникальность обеспечена. 2. Все-таки посмотреть механизм формирования и отсылки этой длинной ссылки - если это ограничения яндекс почты, то тогда укорачивание, если что иное - то нужно бы рассмотреть варианты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, которые могут вам помочь:

1) Если Вы верстаете таблицами и у Вас просто разъезжается часть таблицы Вы можете использовать свойство `table-layout: fixed`. При этом включенном свойстве Вы также можете к `td` применить `position: relative; overflow: hidden;`, как дополнительные меры. Хотя

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

вероятно решит все проблемы, при условии, что верстка письма сделана таблицами.
Подробно об этом свойстве [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#Values)

2) На саму ссылку можно поставить свойство: `word-break: break-all`, что тоже решит проблему.